# Working with TypeScript, Next.js, and Socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, types, next.js

I'm starting a small project that uses TypeScript, Next.js, and Socket.io. I don't understand how to tell TypeScript that I am kind of "merging" these two. For example, here are my files.

`/api/socket.ts`:

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next'
import { Server } from 'socket.io'

const SocketHandler = (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  if (res.socket.server.io) {
    console.log('Socket is already running.')
  } else {
    console.log('Socket is initializing...')

    const io = new Server(res.socket.server)
    res.socket.server.io = io

    io.on('connection', (socket) => {
      socket.on('input-change', (msg) => {
        socket.broadcast.emit('update-input', msg)
      })
    })
  }

  res.end()
}

export default SocketHandler
```

`/components/client.tsx`:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import io from 'socket.io-client'

import type { ChangeEvent } from 'react'
import type { Socket } from 'socket.io-client'

let socket: undefined | Socket

export default function Client() {
  const [input, setInput] = useState('')
  useEffect(() => {
    socketInitializer()
  }, [])

  const socketInitializer = async () => {
    fetch('/api/socket')
    socket = io()

    socket.on('connect', () => {
      console.log('connected')
    })

    socket.on('update-input', (msg) => {
      setInput(msg)
    })
  }

  const onChangeHandler = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setInput(e.target.value)

    if (socket !== undefined) {
      socket.emit('input-change', e.target.value)
    }
  }

  return (
    <input
      placeholder="Type something"
      value={input}
      onChange={onChangeHandler}
    />
  )
}
```

And this code is working. But I'm getting all kinds of warnings / errors, like `"Property 'server' does not exist on type 'Socket'"`, `"Object is possibly 'null'."` (on `res` itself).

I understand the main issue is TypeScript does not know I am adding `.io` on the `res.socket.server` object. But what I don't understand is A) how to tell it that I am adding that `.io`, B) why `res` and `socket` are possibly `null`, and C) why `.server` does not exist on `res.socket`, according to TypeScript.

I just need some direction and possibly higher-level explanation of how to tackle this. I think I need a `.d.ts` file, or maybe I just a new interface, but I am not really sure how to properly write a new interface without over-riding types that are already in place.

Comment: `socket = io()` wouldn't work for me because i had to change the import for io to: `import { io } from 'socket.io-client';`

Answer (score 19):

I found an answer. I don't know if it is the correct way of going about it, but this is what I did.

First I made new TypeScript interfaces, starting with the `.io` property, and moved up all the way back to `res`. All of these extend what `NextApiResponse` already is, and just add new properties.

```js
import type { Server as HTTPServer } from 'http'
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next'
import type { Socket as NetSocket } from 'net'
import type { Server as IOServer } from 'socket.io'

interface SocketServer extends HTTPServer {
  io?: IOServer | undefined
}

interface SocketWithIO extends NetSocket {
  server: SocketServer
}

interface NextApiResponseWithSocket extends NextApiResponse {
  socket: SocketWithIO
}
```

Then I just assigned my new `NextApiResponseWithSocket` to the `res` parameter.

```js
const SocketHandler = (_: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponseWithSocket) => { ... }
```

If there is a better way to do this, I would love to know.

Comment: Which versions of 'socket.io' and 'socket.io-client' are you using? I'm trying to resolve this myself and there seem to be some compatibility issues.

Comment: @Blitva I'm using `socket.io`, `socket.io-client`: 4.5.2, `next`: 12.3.1. Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

If you're looking for a shorter alternative, you can use a type assertion with the `as any` syntax:

`const socket = req.socket as any;`